# Is there a way to make @import work in CSS files within Django?

Tags: css, django, import, django-templates

The CSS stylesheets in my Django website are served as static files (so their URLs are constructed using the `{% static %}` template tag), but I find myself in need of importing a CSS file inside another CSS file, where Django template tags will not work.

Is there a way to dynamically populate the argument to `@import` inside a CSS file? Or will I have to just `<link>` the two files separately inside the HTML page?

Comment: Though it sounds like an okay idea in development but very bad idea in production. How are you planning to serve those files in production?

Comment: They are served through the static files system Django offers, which is set up (and designed) to work in production. What would be the problem with it?